# form action to a similar route that is in two different route group

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a LMS system that are designed based on Laravel

In this system we have a Course , a Lesson and a Test Model. each Course can have some lesson and only one final test , while each lesson can have one Test.

To create Test for Course or Lesson I have only a page contain a Form. to create it I used these:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' =>['TestController@store',$course_id,$lesson_id],  'id'=>'createTestForm')) !!}
```

And routes are these :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'course'], function () {
        Route::group(['prefix' => '/{course_id}'], function () {


            //To Create Final Test of a Course
            Route::resource('test', 'TestController');
            //To Create Final Test of a Course


            Route::group(['prefix' => 'lesson'], function () {

                Route::group(['prefix' => '/{lesson_id}'], function () {


                    //To Create Test of a Lesson
                    Route::resource('test', 'TestController');
                    //To Create Test of a Lesson

                });

            });

            Route::resource('lesson', 'LessonController');
        });

    });
    Route::resource('course', 'CourseController');
```

As you see routes of Test Model repeated inside Course Route Group and Lesson Route Group.

Now When I want to create a Test For a lesson all things works and action attribute of created form is like this :

```
http://lms.dev/course/2/lesson/8/test
```

But on creating a Test Form for a Course, action of form is like :

```
http://lms.dev/course/2/lesson//test
```

While it must be thing like this:

```
http://lms.dev/course/2/test
```

I do not want to create two different page view for that beacause Test Options of Course And Lesson are similar exactly.

I do not know what I should do?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do - do you want to create a page with a form which has both the fields for test and lessons?

Comment: No , only a page contain a form that action of the form can include lesson and lesson_id  or not included

Comment: Ah, you want to use the same form to create and update a lesson?